# Is there a way to accept dhcp response from a specific vendor (not ip)?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I have my dhcp-server(X) and dhcp-clients(Xn) in similar network with other dhcp-servers(Y,Z).

Now, clients(Xn) must accept offer only from server(X) and reject others.

I have googled a bit and found out that

1. One can reject offer from specific ip > [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482684/is-there-a-way-to-refuse-a-dhcp-response-from-a-specific-ip)
2. Put require option in dhclient.conf (not helping bcz same options can send other Y,Z servers)
3. Use vendor-encapsulated-options and make classes in dhcpd.conf.(not helping because can not do like if vendor match then only accept) > [Here](http://isc-dhcp-users.2343191.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-vendor-encapsulated-option-spaces-td117.html)

So. is there any way to achieve my target?

Answer (score 0):

Set static ip and gateway for the Machine

We can set the static ip by the following steps

```
  sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

copy the following lines and paste to the file

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s8 inet static
address 192.168.1.2 
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

Or

Assign IP address based on MAC in server

We can assign the ip based mac address from the following file

if we use isc-dhcp-server package

```
   sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```